# HashMap behaving differently for Custom Key Class

Tags: java, hashmap

For the following snippet, I see that the latest insertion replaces the old, i.e. the data in Line 2 replaces the one in Line 1.

```
 Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();
 someMap.put("A", "101A9901"); // Line 1
 someMap.put("B", "102Z4902");
 someMap.put("A", "103C5389"); // Line 2
```

However, while working with a custom Key class, the old one is retained the new one is never added, i.e. line 1 is not replaced with line 2

```
Order order1 = new Order(101L, 201L, new BigDecimal(284.50), "Preparing");
Order order2 = new Order(102L, 204L, new BigDecimal(780.00), "Dispatched");
Order order3 = new Order(101L, 201L, new BigDecimal(284.50), "Cancelled");
Order order4 = new Order(104L, 207L, new BigDecimal(550.00), "Cancelled");
Order order5 = new Order(105L, 203L, new BigDecimal(320.50), "Confirmed");
Order order6 = new Order(106L, 207L, new BigDecimal(470.00), "Delivered");

Map<Order, String> orderMapAddtionalStatus = new HashMap<>();
orderMapAddtionalStatus.put(order1, "OK"); // line 1
orderMapAddtionalStatus.put(order2, "OK");
orderMapAddtionalStatus.put(order3, "OK"); // line 2
orderMapAddtionalStatus.put(order4, "OK");
orderMapAddtionalStatus.put(order5, "OK");
orderMapAddtionalStatus.put(order6, "OK");
```

I have also overridden the equals and hashCode method. Following are the overridden methods -

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getOrderId().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getCustomerId().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Order)) return false;

        Order order = (Order) o;

        if (!getOrderId().equals(order.getOrderId())) return false;
        return getCustomerId().equals(order.getCustomerId());
    }
```

Can some please tell me what I might be missing?

Comment: map.put finds that an equivalent key to order3 is in the map (order1) and puts on this entry the "OK" value. There is no need to replace order1 by order3. Should be clear if you replace in line 2 "OK" by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at `HashMap.putVal(...)`, the method that is used interally, you'll see the following:

```
if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
        tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
```

This means the key is added to a new node if it wasn't already present.
However, if there already is a key this portion is executed after the node has been found:

```
Node<K,V> e;
... //code to find the existing node

if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
  V oldValue = e.value;
  if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
    e.value = value;
  afterNodeAccess(e);
  return oldValue;
}
```

As you can see, the key is not replaced and that's consistent with the JavaDoc on `put(...)`:

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the oldvalue is replaced.

This states the value is replaced, not the key. From the perspective of the map this is consistent since `equals()` and `hashCode()` state the keys are the same so either of both (the existing and the new key) can be used.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas for such a detailed explanation. I changed the value and it got updated.